# Inverse perspective

Tags: 3d, directx, direct3d

How can I undo the effects of perspective projection (in Direct3D) on the item pointed to in the image below. I want it to look like a rectangular banner (get rid of the trapezoid effect visible).

[image: example]

The view matrix is setup with the camera at (0.0f, 0.8f, 2.5f) pointing at (0, 0, 0) and the item pointed to is drawn parallel with the x axis.

I've tried to draw that item with an orthogonal projection matrix, however I'm stuck on how to find out the screen coordinates of it when in perspective so things line up when being drawn in orthogonal projection. This is part of an animation in which that item comes into focus as they are rotating around the y axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than aligning the box with the axes, you just need to adjust it so that it's flat on to the camera view direction. The normal vector pointing out the front of the item should point directly at the camera.  I think Direct3D has a LookAt function which you can use for this.

You don't need to mess with the projection matrix, unless you also want to get rid of the distance scaling.